# iPhone memory management: a release after setting self.someProperty = nil

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios, memory-management, nsoperation

I am reading the [LazyTableImages code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) that Apple have released and they do something to this effect (in an NSOperation subclass):

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [myProperty release];
    [myProperty2 release];
}

- (void)main {
    //
    // Parse operation undertaken here
    //
    self.myProperty = nil;
    self.myProperty2 = nil;
}
```

My thinking is that they do this ***in case*** `dealloc` **is called before setting properties to nil**.

Is my thinking correct here? **Are the releases unnecessary**, as `self.myProperty = nil` effectively releases `myProperty`?

One thing I have noticed in this code is that they don't `release` all retained objects in `dealloc`, only some of them, which is really the cause for my confusion.

Cheers

Comment: Don't forget to send `[super dealloc]`. You will leak the object if you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do `self.myProperty = nil` or even `[myProperty release]` after `dealloc`.  Know why?  *Because `self` doesn't exist any more.*

As for your question, it appears that the releases in `dealloc` are unnecessary, but it's still good practice to clean up your instance variables in your `dealloc` method.

**edit**

As Peter points out in the comment, if the `-main` method is never executed, then having the release statements in `-dealloc` is necessary; without them, you'd be leaking memory.

Comment: The releases in `dealloc` *are* necessary if `main` is never called (if, for example, this operation is never enqueued) or if either or both of the properties are changed to point to objects again after `main` returns (i.e., after the operation finishes). I'd go to the opposite end: It's `nil`-ing out the properties in `main` that's unnecessary.

Comment: @Peter good point (edited answer).  I was answering under the assumption that `main` would always get invoked.